# Reading cstrings of different length from an input text file into a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, c-strings

I am currently working on an assignment that asks me to read names and other various data from an input text file into a linked list using cstrings. I have completed all the necessary components minus one thing. All but one of the names consists of three words. The last line of the input text file contains only two words, throwing off my loop of reading the input text file properly. The input text file is as follows:

12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Bugs Bunny Jr. 1234 1001.01

Dr. Wiley Coyote 2345 1002.02

Taco Speedy Gonzales 3456 1003.03

Billy the Goat 4567 1004.04

Porky Pig 5678 1005.05

here is my code for the function:

```
void inputfn(customerType *&head){
 customerType *currptr, *nnptr;
 head=NULL;
 fin.ignore(50,'\n');
while(fin){
   //create first node if head is null
   if(head==NULL){
                  head=new customerType;
                  fin>>head->name[0]>>head->name[1]>>head->name[2]>>head->pin>>head->balance;
                  currptr=head;
                  if(fin.peek()=='\n')fin.ignore();//in case there is only one record
                  }//end of first node 

    nnptr=new customerType;

    fin>>nnptr->name[0]>>nnptr->name[1]>>nnptr->name[2]>>nnptr->pin>>nnptr->balance;
    currptr->link=nnptr;//linked the nodes
    currptr=nnptr;//advanced currptr
    if(fin.peek()=='\n')fin.ignore();  
           }//end of while

//end of creating a linked list
 }//end of inputfn
```

Since it is reading three names, the PIN is placed as the last name instead of the actual PIN. This is causing my output to look like this:

Bugs Bunny Jr.       1234 1001.01

Dr. Wiley Coyote     2345 1002.02

Taco Speedy Gonzales 3456 1003.03

Billy the Goat       4567 1004.04

Porky Pig 5678       1005 05

I know there has to be an easy fix to this problem, but since I have to use a loop to read the data, I am having problems finding the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is "an easy fix", but in general, the principle for "I have a line of text that contains a variable number of elements with no distinctive separators" is to read it into a string, and then do the relevant checking whether the input has 1, 2 or 3 elements (consider `Superman 9876 4123.09` as input too).

One approach, would be to count the number of separators (in this case spaces):

```
std:string line;
getline(fin, line);
vector<int> space_loc; 
for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
{
    // Do we have a space? 
    if (line[i] == ' ')
    {
        space_loc.push_back(i);
        // Skip multiple spaces. 
        while(i < line.size() && line[i] == ' ')
        {
        }
    }
}
if (space_loc.size() == 4) 
{
   ...  /* we have three names */
}
else if (space_loc() == 3)
{
   ... /* we only have two names */
}
... more stuff here - remember to add error handling when the data is incomplete.
```

I would also make sure that the code only does one read-statement, rather than two. You could perhaps do:

```
nnptr = new customerType; 

... read into nnptr ... 

if( head == NULL) 
    currptr = head = nnptr;
else
    currptr->next = nnptr;
```

(This also avoids a problem with your code when there is only ONE record in the input file)